# one server multiple clients

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

I am engaging the following problems:

1. I need to write a server program, will accept multiple clients
2. all clients are subscribing the same data from server, for example the stock price update.
3. each clients can send simple commands to server like "logon", "stop"

So here is my solution, Since I am not very experianced in multithread/tcp, I want to know is it a good solution? if not, is there any better solution? is it necessary to have a thread for each client socket? Thanks
BTW: sorry for confusing every one, it is a small project that only involve 5-10 classes.

```
class AcceptThread {
    ......
    public void run () {
        ControlThread controlThread = new ControlThread();
        controlThread.start();

        Socket socket = new Socket(port);
        while (!stop) {
            Socket s = socket.accept();
            controlThread.addClient (s);
        }
    }
}

class ControlThread {
    Set<Scoket> clients;
    SendDataThread sendDataThread;  

    public ControlThread () {
        sendDataThread = new SendDataThread();
        sendDataThread.start();     
    }

    public void addClient (Socket socket) {
        clients.add(socket);
        sendDataThread.addListener(socket);
    }

    public void run () {
        ......
        for (Socket s : clients) {
            if (s.getInputStream().available()) {
                //read command from s
            }
        }
        ......              
    }
}

class SendDataThread () {
    Set<Scoket> listeners;

    public void addListener (Socket s) {
        listeners.add(s);
    }

    public void run () {
        for (Socket s: listeners) {
            // send data to each listener
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless this is homework, you should look at existing solutions like [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) instead of starting from scratch

Comment: Socket dont' have a accept method ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **is it necessary to have a thread for each client socket?**

No, as a matter of fact, I wouldn't even not recommend it. If it's a small project and you don't want to use any existing library, I would suggest you use the [`java.nio` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/io/index.html) and the [`SelectableChannels`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html). With a so called selector you can easily monitor clients for incoming data in a non-blocking way.

Here are a few useful links:

- [NIO Examples (from the official tutorial)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/index.html)
- [The Rox Java NIO Tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html)

Comment: The ROX NIO tutorial is garbage. Guy doesn't even know that closing the channel cancels the key, and he invents a lot of non-existent difficulties about other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about using standards technology for solving this problem?

> JMS topic
>       A distribution mechanism for publishing messages that are delivered
>   to multiple subscribers.

[Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/jms_tutorialTOC.html)

Comment: I consider the JMS system somewhat heavy and doesn't really payoff unless used in large scale. Besides, you'll probably end up using less lightweight application servers to support it (e.g., jboss instead of tomcat/jetty). Good and useful technique in the right project though.

Comment: You are right, the project I am talking about is a small project, do you think my solution is a good one for a small project?

Comment: Absolutely, to me, it's half the effectivity but twice the fun to program socketes. There exist many good high level aids out there, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong in writing socket programming yourself.

Comment: Bence, you are very helpful too. I believe I will use JMS some day when I have some bigger project to develop.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks BTW: sorry for confusing every one, it is a small project that only involve 5-10 classes.

There's definately nothing wrong with it. All higher level abstractions are based on sockets one way or another. Unless your project is sufficiently large there is no need to pull a series other frameworks/toolkit to perform the same job. Threads are cheap (and can even benefit from a multicore architecture), although using `SelectableChannels` as @aioobe suggested is not a bad idea either.

When your projects require it, you can always learn about other inter-process communication methods (message passing, remote method invocaton etc., and its about 100 implementations) then.

You might however want to limit the number of threads you server use simultaneously. This can easily be achieved by claiming e.g., a semaphore of a size equal to the number of threads you want to serve. Another interesting thing to consider is using java [thread pools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to better reuse your resources.

Comment: Beautiful answer. I just disagree on one point: The one-thread-per-client approach is *not* easily adaptable to thread pools, since the whole idea with one-thread-per-client is that it allows you to use blocking io. If you use blocking io, a thread pool won't do you much good.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that you can use the nio library to reduce the number of threads necessary.  i just wanted to point out that your current example code will not work.  you *must* use a thread per socket when using the standard io streams.  the `available()` method is pretty much useless (in general) and will not stop your control thread from blocking.