# Closing infinite InputStream when reading in separate thread causes deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that's reading from an input stream, and (just for simplicity) printing it back out to the console. See below for the code snippet.

I want to be able to terminate this thread at some point, so I should be able to do this by closing the input stream. This should cause an exception to be thrown, interrupting the `BufferedReader::readLine` method, closing the thread.

For some reason, the `close()` invocation just hangs.

What's the reason that this is happening? Is there a way I can close down the thread *without* requiring the user to input any further text?

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ReaderTest readerTest = new ReaderTest(System.in);
    new Thread(readerTest).start();
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    System.out.println("About to close...");
    System.in.close(); // Should cause thread to throw exception and terminate, but just hangs
    System.out.println("All closed...");
  }

  private static class ReaderTest implements Runnable {
    private final InputStream inputStream;

    public ReaderTest(InputStream inputStream) {
      this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: calling 'System.in.available()' also hangs for me, for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason, the close() invocation just hangs.

Your thread is waiting for `readLine()` to release *lock*: You are using a [blocking IO](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html).

```java
public ReaderTest(InputStream inputStream) {
   this.inputStream = inputStream; // This inputStream (in from System.in) is a monitor
}
```

```java
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
}
```

The `readLine()` method proceeds in following steps:

- Take lock on `inputStream` - Here, it's `System.in`
- Go in an infinite loop (**Blocking**) waiting for an input
- When you enter a line (and hit return or enter) on your console, it reads them and returns the output, releasing the lock ***momentarily***
- It then goes into the same infinite (**Blocking**) loop again (You're calling `readLine` in a while loop)

If you provide some input, the *main* thread gets to execute `System.in.close();` (because the reader thread released lock *momentarily*)

So, if you provide an input after 1 second (`Thread.sleep(1000L);`), the `readLine()` will find that stream is closed and it's this time `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` is thrown.

You can see the last line you entered (before `IOException` is thrown) by updating read block as:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    String line = null; // make line reachable inside catch block
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The last line I read before stream was closed : " + line);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, thank you. That is what I observed -- entering some text in the terminal after the sleep has concluded does indeed allow the thread to terminate. In this case, I'd like the thread to close *without* requiring the user to input any further text. Is this possible? I'll amend my question to make the desired answer more clear.

Comment: @EkosIV You can *attempt* to make it non-blocking as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872846/how-to-read-from-standard-input-non-blocking). But, the Streams are designed to be [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049319/how-to-create-a-java-non-blocking-inputstream-from-a-httpsurlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to the `System.in`, changing your main in:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8883);
        InputStream is = socket.accept().getInputStream();
        ReaderTest readerTest = new ReaderTest(is);
        new Thread(readerTest).start();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println("About to close...");
        is.close(); // cause thread to throw exception        System.out.println("All closed...");
    }
```

It does what you expect.

(watch out you need to `telnet` or `nc` to localhost 8883 to let the code pass the `.accept()` method of the socket)